# Embedded Google map doesn't appear in Chrome for iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-maps, google-chrome

I have the following code, [provided in a JSFiddle for your convenience](http://jsfiddle.net/pf9tbtwk/). What it does is provide a Google Map with directions from your device to another location (for purposes of this question, I've hard-coded the destination):

```
(function() {
    var address = "2 15th St NW, Washington, DC 20007";
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function (position) {
                var currentPos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude.toFixed(5), position.coords.longitude.toFixed(5));

                var request = {
                    origin: currentPos,
                    destination: address,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                };

                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
            });
    } else {
        // No starting location can be determined; just plot a marker for the destination
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker.setMap(map);
                marker.setTitle(address);
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Both this script and the linked [Google Maps API script](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false) are in the `<head>` tag of the page.

I'm testing it in various browsers, and everything was working until I tried it in an iPad using Chrome. All I got was a blank grey page—no map controls, no error message, nothing.

However it *does* work in Chrome on my laptop with Windows 7, and in Safari on the very same iPad.

**Update** - The problem lies somewhere with the call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. It is returning a `PositionError`.

What about the iPad-Chrome combination causes this script to fail?

Comment: How do you verify `google.maps` is loaded before execution of this script? google lib in `head`, this script before `</body>` or ... ?

Comment: Both the link to the Google library and this script are in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: So basically the load time for `google maps` could exceed execution of your anonymous function, considering 2 http requests can occur. Can you check the load times -vs- execution times in dev toolbar?

Comment: Also, how do you test? Do you remove cookies? `ctrl+F5`, `apple refresh` to delete cache or just refresh with cache? Sorry voor these obvious questions but I would like to make sure that's ruled out.

Comment: I am refreshing the cache and cookies, but since this behavior is occurring with the JSFiddle I ruled out anything else with *our* site being at fault.

From what I can tell on my laptop, the API is being loaded before the script runs, but it's impossible to tell on the iPad exactly what's going on.

Comment: In google chrome there's a special setting to remove geolocation settings. On another note however, I'm trying your script and gives me an error `TypeError: s is null` somwhere indide `main,places%7D.js line 56 > eval line 81 > eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I'd neglected to check whether Chrome was given permission to get geolocation data on the iPad. Once I enabled it in the Privacy settings, everything worked fine.

Comment: Was going to the same conclusion ^^
And to avoid this, scope `google` object and delay to onload event.

Comment: Yep, just a foolish oversight on my part. Oh well!